# x86 cr3 and linux swqpper_pg_dir

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, osdev, page-tables

In Linux source code (version 2.6.18):

```
movl $swapper_pg_dir-__PAGE_OFFSET,%eax
movl %eax,%cr3
movl %cr0,%eax
orl $0x80000000,%eax
movl %eax,%cr0          /* ..and set paging (PG) bit */
ljmp $__BOOT_CS,$1f     /* Clear prefetch and normalize %eip */
```

And also the `load_cr3(pgdir)` and `write_cr3(x)` macros:

```
#define load_cr3(pgdir) write_cr3(__pa(pgdir))

#define write_cr3(x) \
__asm__ __volatile__("movl %0,%%cr3": :"r" (x))
```

It seems like that the whole `cr3` control register stores the address of Page Directory. However, when I reference the intel ia-32 Developer's_Manual it tells a different story. The following is what the intel manual says:

```
name      0.............11   12.................31
cr3       flags              address of page directory
PDE       flags              address of page table
PTE       flags              address of 4kb page frame
```

The manual says that the 20 most significant bits of `cr3` stores the address of the page directory instead of the whole `cr3` register. It is also reasonable since the page directory is exactly 4kb, so the 12 least significant bits of the address is always zero.

Isn't it a little bit strange? The linux code just assigns the address of the page directory to the `cr3` instead of the 20 most significant bits of the `swapper_pg_dir`. What exactly does the `cr3` register stores, the address or the format that intel manual suggests?

The following link is the intel manual: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Comment: So, what is your question? You know, a sentence with, like, a question mark...

Comment: sorry about that, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 32-bit paging, it is mandatory that the address of the page directory is a multiple of 4096, i.e. its 12 LSB are zero. However, the opcode for setting cr3 loads 32 bits, not 20 bits. When cr3 is loaded, its 20 upper bits are used for the page directory address, and the lower 12 bits are interpreted as flags which may affect paging behaviour in newer processor versions. The "safe" setting for these flags is zero, and that's precisely what Linux does: it loads cr3 with a 32-bit value which happens to have its 12 LSB equal to zero (because that 32-bit value has been taken as a memory address which is a multiple of 4096).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing strange if `swapper_pg_dir-__PAGE_OFFSET` is a multiple of 4096.

Zeroes in CR3 LSBs are valid:

- reserved bits have to be set to 0
- newer (since i80386) functionality can be disabled by setting the relevant bits to 0 as well and generally that's the way to keep x86 CPUs backward compatible with old software.